# Saving user credentials from google sign in with Android?

Tags: android, google-signin

Okey. I integrated a google sign in feature in my android app. 
This is my login activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

//button
private SignInButton signInButton;
//options
private GoogleSignInOptions gso;
//client api
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private static  final int LCD = 4;







@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_login);


    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this,this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(intent,LCD);

        }
    });


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == LCD){

        GoogleSignInResult result =  Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);


    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    //check if the operation  is successful
    if(result.isSuccess()){

        goMainScreen();



    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }




}

private void goMainScreen() {

    Intent secondActivity = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    secondActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(secondActivity);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

Once, login is successful, i open Profile activity, and get the user image and the name
ProfileActivity

```
public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


private ImageView photo;
private TextView name;

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
    photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.theName);

    GoogleSignInOptions gsp = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this,this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gsp)
            .build();

}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();


    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> optionalPendingResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient);

    if(optionalPendingResult.isDone()){

        GoogleSignInResult sig = optionalPendingResult.get();
        handleSigninResult(sig);


    }else {
        optionalPendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                handleSigninResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });

    }

}

private void handleSigninResult(GoogleSignInResult sig) {
    if(sig.isSuccess()){

        GoogleSignInAccount acc =  sig.getSignInAccount();
        //accessing  the data
        name.setText(acc.getDisplayName());

        //image with glide
        Glide.with(this).load(acc.getPhotoUrl()).into(photo);

    }else {
        //in case is not successful
        //send the user to the Login Screen
        goLoginInScree();

    }


}

private void goLoginInScree() {
    Intent goUser = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    goUser.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(goUser);


}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed( ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

My next issue is, how do i implement feature for automatically login in, if the user is already been logged to the activity? I don't want every time app is open, to click Sign in button, but directly to go to profile activity.

Comment: It should work as you already using GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this,this); Which automatically manage the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Login Success in google Authentication, store the result in shared preferences.

```
 private void handleSigninResult(GoogleSignInResult sig) {
    if(sig.isSuccess()){

        GoogleSignInAccount acc =  sig.getSignInAccount();
        //accessing  the data
        name.setText(acc.getDisplayName());
       SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("shared_pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
       editor.putString("email", acc.getEmail());
       editor.putInt("name", acc.getDisplayName());
       editor.putBoolean("hasLogin",true);
       editor.apply();

        //image with glide
        Glide.with(this).load(acc.getPhotoUrl()).into(photo);

    }else {
        //in case is not successful
        //send the user to the Login Screen
        goLoginInScree();
    }    
}
```

Note: Clear the Shared Preference when user logouts

Comment: afaik, this doesn't make sense. Because you need to save the actually account instance so that you can invoke `getIdToken()` later without going throw the sign in process again.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is using SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

after successfully login using Google+, save the credentials detail in Sharedpreferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("email", acc.getEmail());
editor.putInt("name", acc.getDisplayName());
editor.putBoolean("hasLogin",true);  // set the prefs true after success login
editor.apply();
```

then, you can check if user is first time login or not

```
if(prefs.getBoolean("hasLogin")){
    //no need to sigin again.. proceeed to your activity
}
else{
    //need to sign in
}
```

if user want to logout, just revoke Access google sign in including set the prefs "hasLogin" to "false"

Comment: Thank you, i am not sure where should i put this code.